# programmatically select columns for pd.melt

Tags: python, pandas

Working on automating a monthly report.  Trying to find an alternative to manually typing in column names in to `id_vars` and `value_vars` in pandas melt function.  Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Consider a df with columns a, b, c, '12/01/2018', '12/02/2018','12/03/2018', etc. where a,b,c are always the `id_vars` and the daily dates of a given month (Dec in this case) are `value_vars` to be unpivoted.  Instead of writing out

```
pd.melt(id_vars=['a','b','c'],value_vars=['12/01/2018', 
'12/02/2018','12/03/2018', etc.])
```

is it possible to programmatically assign the value_vars to the melt function such that the same code will work for each month? (Jan would have 31 days to unpivot but Feb would have 28).

I'm no pythonista and appreciate any time spent helping me with this.

Comment: What are "a,b,c" and what do they represent? Where do you get those values? I'm assuming they aren't always a,b,c? This question needs a bit more explanation to be clear. For value_vars, are you just looking for a list of dates for the current month in the format MM/DD//YYYY (31 fields for January, etc.)?

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.melt(['a','b','c'])
```

Docstring for df.melt states:

> value_vars : tuple, list, or ndarray, optional
>       Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that
>       are not set as `id_vars`.

Hence, you have set id_vars as he first parameter and all other columns will be used as value_vars per docs.

Comment: Thank you for bringing up what the docs say.  This was the most efficient way to handle what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

If IIUC, you just need to separate your columns. Sets are helpful and fast here. Of course, assuming unique column names (as they should be):

```
id_vars = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
value_vars = set(df.columns) - id_vars
pd.melt(df, id_vars=id_vars, value_vars=value_vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
id_vars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
value_vars = df.columns.difference(id_vars)
pd.melt(df, id_vars=id_vars, value_vars=value_vars)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you!